# Javascript execution order with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, execution, multiple-browsers

Say that I have the following code:

```
function testA {
   setTimeout('testB()', 1000);
   doLong();
}

function testB {
   doSomething();
}

function doLong() {
   //takes a few seconds to do something
}
```

I execute `testA()`.  I have read that Javascript is single-threaded.  What happens after 1000 milliseconds, when the timeout for `testB()` is reached?

Some possibilities I can think of:

- `testB()` is queued up to execute after `doLong()` and anything else it called have finished.
- `doLong()` is immediately terminated and `testB()` is started.
- `doLong()` is given a little while longer to execute before being stopped (either automatically or after prompting the user) and `testB()` is started.
- `doLong()` is paused, `testB()` is started.  After `testB()` has finished, `doLong()` resumes.

What is the correct answer?  Is it implementation dependant or part of the standard?*

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340211/javascript-execution-queue-and-settimeout) is similar but not the same, as far as I can tell.

Any links that you can recommend for better understanding Javascript execution would be appreciated.

Thanks!

*Yes, I know that not all browsers follow standards :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first of your guesses is the correct one:
`testB() is queued up to execute after doLong() and anything else it called have finished.`

If it takes more than one second for `testA` to finish, `testB` will simply have to wait.

Also, you should write `setTimeout(testB, 1000)` rather than `setTimeout('testB()', 1000)`. Sending a string to setTimeout is, like using `eval`, [generally considered evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) and will make you enemies ;)

Comment: I came to believe `setTimeout(function() { testB(); }, 1000);` is the best way, were I misled?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Yes, pretty much misled. As far as I know there's no difference between your way and mine (except that mine is shorter of course :D). To illustrate, imagine if we pulled out your expression into a variable: `var f = function() { testB(); }; setTimeout(f, 1000);`. Still the same meaning, but now you can see the redundancy.

Comment: Thank you, both for the answer and for the advice about passing a function to setTimeout instead of a String.  Looks like the tutorials I've been reading are a little dubious ;)

Comment: As with the latest chrome(ver. 62), this is not the case. testB() will executed first and then doLong() will be executed.